# Dagger 2 giving error '...cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method'

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to build a simple android project for dagger 2 understanding. I currently have the component

MyComponent.java

```
@Component(modules = {MyModule.class})
public interface MyComponent {
    MyModule provideModule();
}
```

MyModule.java

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    @Provides
    Repo provideRepo(){
        return new Repo();
    }
}
```

Repo.java

```
public class Repo {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I've added these to build.gradle for app

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Also in dependencies for project I've used this

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

When building the project, I'm getting this error

```
Error:(10, 14) error: com.example.bharatkulratan.daggernotworking.MyModule cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
```

The error reads out for missing `@Provided` annotation but `provideRepo()`
method is already having the annotation of `@Provided`. I'm unable to figure out the missing part. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this

```
MyModule provideModule();
```

And add this in its place

```
Repo provideRepo();
```